# $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ order nonlinear ODE: $4y''\sqrt{y}=1, y(0)=1, y'(0)=1$

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving this second order nonlinear equation, that is in the title.

My solution is: 
$$ 
\frac{4}{3}(y^{1/2}+c)^{3/2}-4c(y^{1/2}+c)^{1/2}+a=x 
$$ 
where $c$ and $a$ are constants that spawned rom integration. However, I can not see how to find these integration constants if I apply $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=1$.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$$
4y''\sqrt{y}=1\quad\Longrightarrow\quad 4y''y'=\frac{y'}{\sqrt{y}}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
2\big(y'\big)^2=2\big(\sqrt{y}\big)+c,
$$
for some $c$ constant, which is equal to zero, due to the initial data.

Hence
$$
\big(y'\big)^2=\sqrt{y}\quad\Longrightarrow^*\quad y'=y^{1/4}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad y^{-1/4}y'=1 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad\frac{y^{3/4}}{3/4}=t+c'.
$$
$y'=y^{1/4}$ and not $y'=-y^{1/4}$ due to the initial data. Also,
$$
c=\frac{4}{3},
$$
again due to the initial condition, and hence
$$
y(t)=\left(\frac{3t}{4}+1\right)^{4/3}.
$$

Comment: Very nice solution! Just that i was solving by substituting y'=a and arrived at that gigantic answer. I am wondering if i could somehow find constants from my answer, but yours solution is much more rational, thanks

Comment: $ 2(y')^2=2(y)^{1/2}+c $, how do you know that c here is 0? may be a silly question, but i dont know how can you see this from initial conditions